# How release a object with is calling a delegate function to release itself

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, uiviewcontroller

I think this is simple, but I am having big problem with this.

I have 2 `UIViewController`, one is the "**Central**" controller and other is for use the camera to decode a barcode.

In **Central** `UIViewController`, I call to run the barcode:

```
   barCode = [[MyBarCode alloc] init]
   [barCode openBarCodeReader];
   //[barCode release];  //can't release it here, this cause problem with camera
}  //function finish
```

The `MyBarCode` object will take control of the program. First it create a simple view to UIViewController

```
- (void) loadView {
    UIView *frame = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [frame setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    self.view = frame;
}
```

Than start and configure the BarCode objects and start the camera with a

```
[self presentModalViewController:barCodeView animated:YES];
```

Now, some time later, I have to dismiss this controller

```
[barCodeView dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I send the data with a delegate function, and now this `UIViewController` finish their job and have to be released. I tried somethings:

1. Send another delegate message. But, if I do `[barCode release];` in this delegate, the program crash, because the barCode object is still running and need go to next instruction
2. I can send a `[self release]` but i don't know if it work and where the program will go in the "Central" `UIViewController` after it.
3. I can dismiss this aux `UIViewController` with a

   ```
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
   ```

   But again, where the program go in the **Central** `UIViewController`.

Anyone have idea to solve this problem?

** Edit **

Maybe I found the answer: 
I will not call the delegate like a method

```
[theDelegate BarCodeFinish];
```

But call it with a notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"BarCodeFinish" object:nil];
```

The fist case I still will run the next code after that call, but in the second, the call will run after it finish the function it is inside, and I can release the barcode object with no problem. Is this the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand the second view controller which take control of your program is presented modaly and you looking for a way to dismiss the view controller and release the bar code ?

In my opinion this should be done in a delegate method. For example :

```
-(void)barCodeReader:(UIViewController *)aViewController didReadBarCode:(NSUInteger)theBarCode;
```

Write that method in your first view controller, then set it as the delegate of the second.
You can even better write your own protocol... But, once the second view controller has read the bar code call your custom method.
A way to implement it should be :

```
-(void)barCodeReader:(UIViewController *)aViewController
      didReadBarCode:(NSUInteger)theBarCode {
    // stop the bar code reader
    [barCode release];
    // dismiss the second view controller
    // do something with theBarCode
}
```

Once that method returns, your app will wait for the next event, probably some Internet provided data, after sending the code.

I used `NSUInteger` as the argument but you can set a type of your own.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hum.. Maybe I write a little wrong. It's look like a C function. All I want to do is simple: `result = [barCode openBarCodeReader]` then `[barcode release]`. I can't do this, because it will open the camera (and I can't release barcode because it go to this line before I open the camera). When the camera decode something, it send a function to barcode object. Now I want to return this to Central view (or central object, is the same). I use a delegate to send this data. The `Central` can continue with this. But I have to release the barcode. If I release barcode and it go to next line, it crash

Comment: I think I find the solution. I can send a  `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"BarCodeFinish" object:nil];`. This will run outside the object and I can release it. I don't like to use this GOTO style... But, thanks for your time.

Comment: Rodrigo, isn't MyBarCode a sort of wrapper class for a bar code ? Or is it a custom UIViewController subclass ?
Isn't the second view controller supposed to manage the camera, while the central one manage the second and wait for it to decode something. The delegation design pattern is typically used in such cases.If `MyBarCode` is a wrapper class, *don't* let it set up the camera, capture the code... If not, what your `openBarCodeReader` is suppose to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just autorelease?

```
barCode = [[[MyBarCode alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Comment: I think I don't understand a lot of the autorelease. Did it only used for function variable? My question always was: when it will be release. I think is after the end of function, and I need to have another function in this case.

Comment: No its not immediately after the function. Autorelease will release the object when it is no longer in use. Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439884/when-is-the-autorelease-pool-triggered/3442414#3442414